# Word suggestion for "slamming against the wall"

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I have a very clumsy habit of getting my arm **slammed/rammed** against the wall. It happens more often when I suddenly get down the bed and rush past my bedroom door. It is just that my feet doesn't get accustomed to the sudden movements after sitting in the bed for an hour or two long. My friends often ask me "*Do I get beaten at my home?*" and I am actually quite perplexed by that question, but the thing is, I am not beaten. I just have this habit of getting my arm bruised somehow or the other and then people regard it as abuse.

How do I convey this sentence effectively:

> It is nothing major. I just **slammed/rammed/ran (into)** into the wall on my way out of the house.

Should I continue using the highlighted word, or is their any compact term (scientific or colloquial or formal) to highlight my situation without leaving a doubt in their mind? I mean I don't want them to build a negative thought about my family.

Comment: Perhaps you **knock** your arm against the wall. The same word is used for other body parts, such as "he was taken to hospital after a bad knock on the head."

Comment: I might say I **bash** my arm against the wall, in informal conversation.

Comment: I suggest "I just banged my arm on/against the wall.